# Jquery, disable / ignore hover event during fade in / out?

Tags: jquery, hover, fadein

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible.. I have an image map that does fade in / fade out based on  hovers over certain parts.. the problem is that when the user hovers to a different area during the fade it finishes the fade it was doing then does the one for the area the mouse was moved to.. if the user moves quickly between a few different areas then the fades appear really jumpy and awkward, so I want to be able to disable the hover event (the fade) during the time that another fade is going on so it just ignores it..

I have thought about using some sort of delay but I don't know if this can work since I would think it would delay the fade too.. any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to [queue buildup](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup) problem there. Try using the [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method before the animation method eg:

```
$(...).stop().fadeIn();
```

More Info:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

As for smooth animation, you can go for [jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Comment: Thanks.. that helps, it was a matter of me not really knowing the right terminology to search for info on this, I will look at the inf you gave

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing your code, your tools are a mix of `:animated` and jQuerys `.stop()` method.

That could look like

```
$('imagemap').hover(function(){
   // only do something if no animation is in process (like fading)
   if(!$(this).is(':animated')){
   }
}, function(){
});
```

You might also call `.stop(true, true)` before any `.fadeIn()` in your chain. That will stop the current animation and jump to the end of the `fx queue`.

References: [:animated selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/), [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: Thanks.. I got it figured out now, just didn't know what terminology to search for I guess