# jQuery - terminating animation

Tags: jquery, animation, terminate

I'm experiencing an issue when I have a code like:

```
  $("#clickme").click(function () {
  $("#status").fadeIn(250).delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
   });
```

This shows after a user successfully saves some info - problem is that when you click on a #clickme button multiple times (fast) then the animations get in some kind of queue and they are executing one after another. That is bad. I would like something like when a user clicks on the button multiple times the previous animation would stop and the new one starts from the beginning.

Also when the #status is currently visible and the user clicks it again - the status would dissapear and the new animation would start over.

Can anyone please give me some direction? Ive been trying to resolve this for days.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3FvL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try to use .clreaQueue(); this will work for u

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
     $("#status").clearQueue();
     $("#status").fadeIn(250).delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
   });
```

[see here](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)

Comment: +1 That seems correct, would you mind expanding this to work in the OP's code from above?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum actually my intention is to give quick reply then i will expand it.

Comment: @Richard Šůstek did you check my answer

Comment: @Baadshah you can check it once now

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. Nice going with clreaQueue. Didnt know it existed. Along with stop() very good and easy solutions:)

Comment: @PSR: I found some issues, at first it seemed ok, but in further testing the stop() method does not help here. Your solution is better but see this examole: I click on the button, I wait for 1.5 seconds and click it again. Now I would like the animation to start over so it would last again 2.5 seconds. However it will end in 1sec. (2.5-1.5).

Comment: @Baadshah  did you see my updated code once.I have a typo in previous code

Comment: @PSR its ok Samba,I'm just informing.

Comment: @PSR This example prevents from adding multiple stack into the queue, however it will not "replace" the old animation with a new ne. See my previous comment.

Comment: @RichardŠůstek If you feel that PSR's answer solved your problem, consider accepting it (also try using clearQueue().stop() )

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that your status isn't animated yet:

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
  var $status = $("#status");
  $status.stop(true).hide();
  $status.fadeIn(250).delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
});
```

Comment: Alright, check my edit to get what you may really expect ;) http://jsfiddle.net/UHTHN/

Comment: Thanks again for updating, unfortunately still does not work without bugs -> try playing with a little - some multiple clicks followed by a break. You see that the interval 2.5sec for displaying status will get shorter. Sometimes it even dissapears immediately. Im sorry, I had no idea this issue is followed by so many problems.

Comment: Indeed, instant `hide()` make things nicer. I think you will be okay with this. Else you'll have to work with jQuery `queue()`! Post & fiddle are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328712/jquery-disable-ignore-hover-event-during-fade-in-out) method like this :

```
$("#status").stop(true).fadeIn(250).delay(2500).fadeOut(250);
```

In the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3FvL/9/), it works. (with the `true` param.)

[EDIT] (add many status)
Does this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3FvL/10/) do what you're attempting?

Comment: Stop method also does not result in a succsefull scenario.

Comment: Thanks for updating, however there is still an issue. Say I have a multiple save buttons. Now when a user clicks save and then again save in 2.499 seconds I would like user to know that the information was stored. In this example it will dissapear in 0.01 seconds.